# Nexus 3 OSS bundle requires license for PRO

Tags: nexus

When accessing the Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.2.1-01 through the webinterface I'm redirected to http://host:port/#admin/system/licensing and in the upper left corner it says "PRO 3.2.1-01".

I downloaded the OSS bundle and did the following:

`tar xvzf nexus-3.2.1-01-unix.tar.gz
cd nexus-3.2.1-01/bin
./nexus start`

Then hit the browser and is required a license for PRO.

The same bundle on any other server behaves as an OSS edition. Possible important hints of the given server:

- We're running an OSS 2.x.
- The server has previously been running a PRO 2.x edition but that's completely wiped.

I'll attach an excerpt from the log:

`2017-03-09 21:03:02,300+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Replaced standard System.out and System.err PrintStreams with SLF4JPrintStreams
2017-03-09 21:03:02,315+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Redirected System.out and System.err to SLF4J for this context
2017-03-09 21:03:02,330+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder - Properties:
2017-03-09 21:03:02,330+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   application-host='0.0.0.0'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   application-port='8085'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   fabric.etc='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/fabric'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   jetty.etc='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.base='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.data='/home/nexus/nexus3/sonatype-work/nexus3'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.etc='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/karaf'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.home='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.instances='/home/nexus/nexus3/sonatype-work/nexus3/instances'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,331+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   logback.etc='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/logback'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,332+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-args='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty.xml,/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-http.xml,/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-requestlog.xml'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,332+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-context-path='/'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,332+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-edition='nexus-pro-edition'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,332+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-features='nexus-pro-feature'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,332+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   ssl.etc='/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/ssl'
2017-03-09 21:03:02,333+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - Java: 1.8.0_121, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Oracle Corporation, 25.121-b13
2017-03-09 21:03:02,333+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - OS: Linux, 4.4.0-47-generic, amd64
2017-03-09 21:03:02,333+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - User: nexus, en, /home/nexus
2017-03-09 21:03:02,333+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - CWD: /home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01
2017-03-09 21:03:02,347+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - TMP: /home/nexus/nexus3/sonatype-work/nexus3/tmp
2017-03-09 21:03:02,354+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Starting
2017-03-09 21:03:02,367+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @5282ms
2017-03-09 21:03:02,370+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty.xml
2017-03-09 21:03:02,615+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-http.xml
2017-03-09 21:03:02,675+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/home/nexus/nexus3/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-requestlog.xml
2017-03-09 21:03:02,700+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Starting: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@b374015
2017-03-09 21:03:02,709+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.7.v20160115
2017-03-09 21:03:02,803+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Initializing
2017-03-09 21:03:02,813+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Installing: nexus-pro-edition/3.2.1.01
2017-03-09 21:03:04,575+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Installed: nexus-pro-edition/3.2.1.01`

This is different from the same bundle on another server:

`2017-03-09 20:34:12,413+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Replaced standard System.out and System.err PrintStreams with SLF4JPrintStreams
2017-03-09 20:34:12,415+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Redirected System.out and System.err to SLF4J for this context
2017-03-09 20:34:12,420+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder - Properties:
2017-03-09 20:34:12,420+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   application-host='0.0.0.0'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,420+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   application-port='8081'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,420+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   fabric.etc='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/fabric'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   jetty.etc='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.base='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.data='/home/hotell-test/temp/sonatype-work/nexus3'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.etc='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/karaf'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.home='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   karaf.instances='/home/hotell-test/temp/sonatype-work/nexus3/instances'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   logback.etc='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/logback'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-args='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty.xml,/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-http.xml,/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-requestlog.xml'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,421+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-context-path='/'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,422+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-edition='nexus-pro-edition'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,422+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-features='nexus-pro-feature'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,422+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   ssl.etc='/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/ssl'
2017-03-09 20:34:12,422+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - Java: 1.8.0_111, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Oracle Corporation, 25.111-b14
2017-03-09 20:34:12,422+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - OS: Linux, 3.13.0-107-generic, amd64
2017-03-09 20:34:12,422+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - User: hotell-test, en, /home/hotell-test
2017-03-09 20:34:12,423+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - CWD: /home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01
2017-03-09 20:34:12,424+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - TMP: /home/hotell-test/temp/sonatype-work/nexus3/tmp
2017-03-09 20:34:12,428+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Starting
2017-03-09 20:34:12,438+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @5248ms
2017-03-09 20:34:12,441+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty.xml
2017-03-09 20:34:12,533+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-http.xml
2017-03-09 20:34:12,549+0100 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/home/hotell-test/temp/nexus-3.2.1-01/etc/jetty/jetty-requestlog.xml
2017-03-09 20:34:12,563+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Starting: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@7487cb12
2017-03-09 20:34:12,571+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.7.v20160115
2017-03-09 20:34:12,641+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Initializing
2017-03-09 20:34:12,642+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Loading OSS Edition
2017-03-09 20:34:12,643+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Installing: nexus-oss-edition/3.2.1.01
2017-03-09 20:34:14,551+0100 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Installed: nexus-oss-edition/3.2.1.01`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you've wiped the Nexus 2.x instance, the license is still installed on the system. Since Nexus Repository 2 and 3 both share a common license (this was by design, so if you buy support, it should work for both).

To remove the existing license, get into the Karaf Console (there is info here on how to do so, if you are unfamiliar: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/bundle-development.html#bundle-development-installing) in Nexus 3.2.1 and run the following command:

`nexus:license -m remove`

Restart Nexus Repository 3.2.1 after you've done this, and it should boot as OSS.

Also, please pop over to https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS and file an issue for what you are experiencing. If the command doesn't work for some reason, make a note of that as well, and we will get you fixed up!

You could also run Nexus Repository as a different user, as the license is installed per OS user.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I'll come back as soon as I get the opportunity to try it out. Just that I might be out of office for a while.